# superscalar CPUs and data dependencies

Tags: cpu

I'm learning about superscalar CPUs and I had a question about that and data dependencies. Given the dependencies, RAW  (read after write), WAR  (write after read), WAW  (write after write), when would the ROB (re-order buffer) NOT be used?

Comment: I suspect you're not going to have much luck getting that question answered here.

(On the other hand, who knows what wisdom is lurking amongst the populace?)

Comment: Any other places where this question would be more appropriate?

Comment: Sorry, Fred-- your guess is as good, or perhaps better, than mine.

Comment: Do you know any of your classmates? Maybe ask one of them? :)

Comment: Maybe StackOverflow would be a good place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while for me, too, so take this with a grain of salt.  But I don't see why you would need the ROB for WAW and WAR.  Register renaming can get around those dependencies while executing in-order.  Only for RAW would the CPU potentially have to wait for the result, and so CPU would go searching through the instruction window for something else to execute out-of-order.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time since I took a course in computer architecture so I'm not even going to attempt to answer your question from memory. However I do remember talking extensively about super scalars and the textbook we used was great.

[Computer Architecture: A Quantitative Approach, 4th Edition 
~ David A. Patterson, John L. Hennessy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001KYEI0I)

Answer (score 0):

In superscalar processors we use register renaming to avoid WAW and WAR hazards and we prefer using ROB for RAW. so iff you assume we are using register renaming we will not be using ROB in WAR and WAW.